# Bash function to count the number of nested parentheses

Tags: bash, function

I would like to create a bash function that, given a string, it count the depth level of nested parentheses, and return -1 if the parentheses are not balanced:

```bsh
function countNested(){
  str="$1"
  n_left=$(echo $str | grep -o '(' | grep -c '(' )
  n_right=$(echo $str | grep -o ')' | grep -c ')' )
  
  # if the n_left is not equal to n_right return -1
  [[ $n_left -ne n_right ]] && { echo -1; return -1 ; }
  [[ $n_left -ge 1 ]] && echo $((n_left-1))
  [[ $n_left -eq 0 ]] && echo 0
}
```

When I try it:

```
countNested '((((((5)))'
# output: -1

countNested '((((((((((((((((5+7))))))))))))))))'
# output: 15
```

I am using grep two times which seems to be expensive. Any ideas how can I increase the performance of that function?

Comment: how about `countNested '(5))('`, it returns `1` but the parens aren't actually balanced. You could do that character-by-character with a shell loop, but if you care about performance, you might want to do it with some other tool.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Oh thank you. I was too naive to assume that implementation of that function works correctly.

Comment: Probably I would need also to check if the string ends with an opening parentheses and vice versa

Comment: that in itself doesn't help, it could be `(5))(()` which again has an equal number of both (and would be valid with an extra pair of surrounding parens!), but which isn't valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the check character-by-character, that'd let you detect cases where there is a right parenthesis without the corresponding left one. You could do it Bash, but if you care about performance, some other tool is probably better. E.g. with awk:

```
$ cat parens.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    n = 0;
    max = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= length($0); i++) {
        c = substr($0, i, 1);
        if (c == "(") n++;
        if (c == ")") n--;
        if (c == ")" && n < 0) {
            printf "mismatching right parenthesis at position %d\n", i > "/dev/stderr";
            exit 1;
        }
        if (n > max) max = n;
    }
    if (n != 0) {
        printf "%d left parentheses left unclosed\n", n > "/dev/stderr";
        exit 1;
    }
    # maximum nesting level
    printf "%d\n", max;   
    exit 0;
}
```

The output is just the maximum nesting level, or a message to stderr if the input is invalid:

```
$ echo '((5))' | awk -f parens.awk 
2
$ echo '((5)' | awk -f parens.awk 
1 left parentheses left unclosed
$ echo '((5)))' | awk -f parens.awk 
mismatching right parenthesis at position 6
$ echo '(5))(' | awk -f parens.awk 
mismatching right parenthesis at position 4
$ echo '((5)(6))' | awk -f parens.awk 
2
$ echo '((5)))' | awk -f parens.awk 
mismatching right parenthesis at position 6
```

Also, the exit status is one on error, so you can also do:

```
if ! level=$( echo '((5)))' | awk -f parens.awk 2>/dev/null); then
    echo invalid parenthesis
fi
```

(Or just remove the `print`s for the error messages if you don't care about them.)

If you want to do it in Bash, `${var:i:1}` gives the character in `var` at position `i`, `${#var}` gives the length of the variable.

Comment: When I run it with `))(` I get a wrong error message

Comment: ```mismatching right parenthesis at position 1
mismatching right parenthesis at position 2
mismatching right parenthesis at position 3
-1 left parentheses left unclosed
```

Comment: @OK-Validation, ah, yes of course, it should only print that if the current character is `)`, not when going back "up" from negative. Fixed. Though I'm not sure if it's even that useful to print all mismatched right parens, rather than just note the error once.

Comment: with `(()` I get 1 left parentheses left unclosed
maximum nesting level 2 it shouldn't print the maximum nesting level2 since it is not balanced

Comment: @OK-Validation, well, yes, it might be better to just exit with an error

Answer (score 4):

With `bash`'s own pattern matching operators, you could do something like:

```
shopt -s extglob
count_nested() {
  local string="$1" new count=0
  until
    new=${string//'('*([^'()'])')'}
    [[ "$string" = "$new" ]]
  do
    string=$new
    (( ++count ))
  done
  case $string in
    (*['()']*) echo -1; false;;
    (*)        echo "$count";;
  esac
}
```

That is work your way from the inside out removing the inner `(...)` pairs first and stop when there are no matched parens left.

To remove the inner `(...)`, we use the `${param//pattern[/replacement]}` replacement operator from ksh93 here with a pattern using ksh extended operators (a subset of which is enabled in `bash` with the `extglob` option): `'('*([^'()'])')'`.

That matches on `(` followed by 0 or more `*(...)` characters other than `(` or `)` (`[^'()']`) followed by `)`.

So that's a `(...)` that doesn't contain `(`/`)`.

The `(`s and `)`s need to be quoted as they're otherwise special in the shell's syntax. To make it more legible, you can store the pattern in a variable:

```
local pattern='(*([^()]))'
...
new=${string//$pattern}
```

Having it in a variable also avoids problems when the function is *parsed* (let alone run) when the `extglob`  option is not enabled. It then allows you to set that option from within the function, possibly in a subshell so it's confined there¹:

```
count_nested() (
  shopt -s extglob
  string="$1" count=0 pattern='(*([^()]))'
  until
    new=${string//$pattern}
    [[ "$string" = "$new" ]]
  do
    string=$new
    (( ++count ))
  done
  case $string in
    (*['()']*) echo -1; false;;
    (*)        echo "$count";;
  esac
)
```

(note the body of the function is now a `(...)` subshell instead of a `{...;}` command group).

---

<sup>¹ as `bash` has no local scope support for its set of options set with `shopt` yet. Also beware its subshells are implemented by forking a child process, so that makes it less efficient.</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand this substitution; what is substituted by what `${string//'('*([^'()'])')'}`

Comment: @OK-Validation see edit

Comment: I think I understand now. But honestly the part that confused me at the beginning was `{var//foo}` I was interpreting `//` as `g` in `sed` so I was wondering what is the replacement. So finally I understand it as `sed /pattern//`

Comment: One last question: Is it possible to turn on the extended globbing inside the function at the beginning then disable it again when the function quits?

Comment: @OK-Validation see edit